# Creating a multidimensional array from prexisting arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I currently have 3 associative arrays I need to turn into one multidimensional array. I feel like the solution is elementary but I cant seem to find it online.

The arrays are pretty lengthy as they are pulling data from MySQL tables I have on my backend So I would prefer not to write out the arrays by hand or if there is an easier way to do this other than using a loop. I am then serializing the arrays so I can pass them through a 'hidden' input on my form.

So how would i turn:

```
Array1[]
Array2[]
Array3[]
```

into

```
BigArray[Array1[],Array2[],Array3[]];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not pull them out of the DB into the same larger array?

Comment: How about `$newArray[] = $array1; $newArray[] = $array2;`?

Comment: Also, this does not sound good _I am then serializing the arrays so I can pass them through a 'hidden' input on my form._

Comment: "How about $newArray[] = $array1; $newArray[] = $array2;" 
wouldnt that overwrite newArray[] ?

Unfortunately I cannot pull from multiple tables as the headers may overlap. Also, why is serializing the arrays a bad idea?

Comment: ` $newArray[]` creates a new element in ` $newArray` and assigns to it.  Whay are you passing DB results from page to page via a form?  Why not query for it on the next page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to set them as arrays inside the larger array when you pull the arrays out of the database, however just this after the fact:

```
$BigArray = [$Array1, $Array2, $Array3];
//or
$BigArray = array($Array1, $Array2, $Array3);
```

An example for fetching from the database:

```
//query
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $Array1[] = $row;
}
$BigArray[] = $Array1;

//query
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $Array2[] = $row;
}
$BigArray[] = $Array2;
```

Comment: This did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php): is here for this :)

```
$bigArray = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);
```

Answer (score -1):

very simple

```
BigArray[] = Array1;
BigArray[] = Array2;
BigArray[] = Array3;
```

this will make BigArray (multi-dimensional) array. If you don't want multi-dimensional array, then you should change your logic like this

```
BigArray[] = implode(',', Array1);
BigArray[] = implode(',', Array2);
BigArray[] = implode(',', Array3);
```

Comment: wouldnt this overwrite the array?

Comment: no, this will create a numeric array. like BigArray[0] = Array1;
BigArray[1] = Array2;
BigArray[2] = Array3;

Comment: Unfortunately it's not PHP.